# Error al instalar angular/cli en Ubuntu

Tags: angular, ubuntu, angular-cli

Hola estoy instalando angular en mi pc (ub

con el siguiente comando `sudo npm install -g @angular/cli` 
cuento con

npm -v
6.10.1

node -v
v12.6.0

y me genera el siguiente error

```
sudo npm install -g @angular/cli
sudo: imposible resolver el anfitrión P8534
npm ERR! code EPROTO
npm ERR! errno EPROTO
npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcli failed,       reason: write EPROTO 139783343089472:error:1408F10B:SSL  routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/record/ssl3_record.c:332:
npm ERR! 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/desarrollo/.npm/_logs/2019-07-16T20_21_44_897Z-debug.log
```

Adicionalmente intente hacer un *npm cache clear* y me genero el siguiente error:

```
As of npm@5, the npm cache self-heals from corruption issues and data extracted from the cache is guaranteed to be valid. If you want to make sure everything is consistent, 
use 'npm cache verify' instead. On the other hand, if you're debugging an issue with the installer, you can use 
 `npm install --cache /tmp/empty-cache` to use a temporary cache instead of nuking the actual one.
```

Si alguien me puede orientar de como solucionarlo, muchas gracias!

Comment: Cristian, instalaste npm con permiso de administrador?

Comment: Franco, si mal recuerdo ejecute `sudo apt-get install npm` , voy a intentar instalarlo nuevamente

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo pude resolver ejecutando el siguiente comando

`npm install --cache /tmp/empty-cache`

Ademas, si trabajas en un lugar con proxy no olvidar de configurar:

```
 npm config set proxy http://proxy.empresa.com:80
 npm config set https-proxy http://proxy.empresa.com:80
```